# Magento: frontName + controllerName + actionName and the catalogue's category pages

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I would like to know what handles are loaded when I go to the Magento installed web application's front end's home page and click on a product category on the header.
For instance, suppose I go to http:// localhost/mymagento and then click on the Clothing link which should bring me to http:// localhost/mymagento/clothing.html . Here I don't see the format frontName + controllerName + actionName after /mymagento/ so how do I know what handles are going to be gathered from this HTTP request?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an internal URL rewrite to `catalog/category/view` - see `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front::dispatch()`, `Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite::rewrite()`, and the `core_url_rewrite` table. So, `catalog_category_view` is the full action name.

There are several other handles loaded as well. These can be retrieved via `Mage_Core_model_Layout_Update::getHandles()`.